# Concatenating a variable + string in Jade file

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug

I am passing in a session variable from my mongodb session store in an Express for Node.js web app like this:

```
exports.dashboard = function(req, res){
    res.render('dashboard', {pref: req.session.layoutpref});
}
```

Then, in my Jade file I'm trying to assign the value of `pref` to the css link like this, but I'm getting a syntax error:

```
head
        title #{title}
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/' + #{pref} + '.css')
```

I'm almost certain the problem is in my concatenation of `pref` into the location of the css file to be used. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

use `#{}` notation if you want to interpolate a variable in the contents of an element. you can just use the variable names straight up if you want to use them in attributes.

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/' + pref + '.css')
```

equivalent:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/' + locals.pref + '.css')
```

when to use `#{}`:

```
a(href='/stylesheets/' + locals.pref + '.css') View the stylesheet at #{pref}
```

Answer (score 5):

Jade files are compiled in Node.js env.

Node.js (from v4.0.0) supports [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), so

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href=`/stylesheets/${pref}.css`)
```

equivalent:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/' + pref + '.css')
```